# FMA: proof performance

Tags: floating-point, z3

I'm experimenting with the new FP logic. Alas, even the simplest of queries related to FMA seem to be causing z3 quite a bit of trouble.

Following is one such instance, where I tried to prove `x*y+0` is equal to `fma(x,y,0)`. It does a couple of extra things to make sure `x` and `y` are not `NaN`s, etc so the equality would indeed hold. Is there a reason why this benchmark is causing so much trouble for `z3`?

My `z3` version: `Z3 [version 4.3.2 - 64 bit - build hashcode 728835357594].`

```
(set-option :produce-models true)
(set-logic QF_FPA)
(define-fun s3 () (_ FP  8 24) (as plusInfinity (_ FP 8 24)))
(define-fun s5 () (_ FP  8 24) (as minusInfinity (_ FP 8 24)))
(define-fun s17 () (_ FP  8 24) ((_ asFloat 8 24) roundNearestTiesToEven (/ 0 1)))
(declare-fun s0 () (_ FP  8 24))
(declare-fun s1 () (_ FP  8 24))
(assert
   (let ((s2 (== s0 s0)))
   (let ((s4 (< s0 s3)))
   (let ((s6 (> s0 s5)))
   (let ((s7 (and s4 s6)))
   (let ((s8 (and s2 s7)))
   (let ((s9 (== s1 s1)))
   (let ((s10 (< s1 s3)))
   (let ((s11 (> s1 s5)))
   (let ((s12 (and s10 s11)))
   (let ((s13 (and s9 s12)))
   (let ((s14 (and s8 s13)))
   (let ((s15 (not s14)))
   (let ((s16 (* roundNearestTiesToEven s0 s1)))
   (let ((s18 (+ roundNearestTiesToEven s16 s17)))
   (let ((s19 (fusedMA roundNearestTiesToEven s0 s1 s17)))
   (let ((s20 (== s18 s19)))
   (let ((s21 (or s15 s20)))
   (not s21)))))))))))))))))))
(check-sat)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Z3 solves floating-point formulas by translating them to bit-vector formulas (and then SAT). There are some methods that are quicker than this on some formulas (e.g., ACDCL based or some forms of approximation refinement), but on this particular formula I would expect all of them to exhibit poor performance. Multiplication (and similar) constraints are usually hard for the underlying engine, and proving that multiplication preserves some property is even harder.

Comment: I'd have thought you'd have a rewrite rule `fma(x,y,0) = x*y` under certain conditions satisfied by `x` and `y`, but I do understand one-off rules such as these are unlikely to help for arbitrary benchmarks.

Comment: Exactly, there are a few such rules, but that particular one isn't there. FPA is quite complicated, and before adding such a rule I would have to make sure what exactly happens under each rounding mode, e.g., is fma(x,y,-0) still x*y for all rounding modes? But yes, there aren't many benchmarks yet and this particular rule wouldn't help on the ones we have so far.

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger of course, you could use Z3 with quantifiers to prove this identity.

Comment: @usr @ChristophWintersteiger Indeed you are justified being skeptical about the `fma (x, y, 0) --> x*y` rule. It doesn't hold when `x = -1`, `y = 0`, as the left hand side evaluates to `+0`, while the right hand side evaluates to `-0`. And this is true regardless of the rounding mode! (While `-0` compares equal to `0`, this wouldn't be a valid rewrite rule as the two can be distinguished via a predicate like `isNZero`.)